# How to do bulk insert / update (best performance) entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Im trying to do an update / insert of about 100 records:

```
public static bool SaveTemplates(List<SecurityTemplateItemModel> templates)
        {

            try
            {
                using (SecurityDS service = new SecurityDS())
                {
                    foreach (var item in templates)
                    {
                        if (item.IsNew)
                        {
                            // insert
                            service.AddToSecurityTemplateExceptions(new SecurityTemplateException()
                            {
                                ObjectId = item.ObjectId,
                                AccessType = item.AccessType,
                                PlatformType = item.PlatformType,
                                TemplateUid = item.TemplateUid
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            // update
                            var exception = service.SecurityTemplateExceptions.Where(e => e.ObjectId == item.ObjectId && e.TemplateUid == item.TemplateUid).FirstOrDefault();
                            exception.AccessType = item.AccessType;
                            exception.PlatformType = item.PlatformType;

                            service.UpdateObject(exception);
                        }
                    }

                    service.SaveChanges();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Im using Data Services, and don't know if the performance issue comes from there. But the function checks if the entity is new then add to the collection if not then get the Entity Framework entity and update some value and then Update the object and finally save the changes.

This process takes about 15 seconds, and it should work in 1 or 2 seconds.

Any clue on how to do this? or if there is a better way?

Comment: Is your `SecurityDS` a DbContext?

Comment: is DataService reference. But I think is almost the same, just a layer in the middle.

Comment: What I dont like is that on each loop I have to check if the entity extist, then update values. I think that's bad performance, maybe better with ADO.NET and a Stored Proc.

Comment: From you're code, you're simply checking a bool property, so there should be no performance issues with that unless it's a hidden get method with a complex implementation underneath. Put some Stopwatches and check WHERE you're code is getting slow, might help.

Comment: It may be a lazy loading problem.  Are any of the properties that you are getting from item associated entities?  Try turning off lazy loading for the function.

Answer (score 0):

I just change from using **DataServices** to just **WCF Services** exposing POCO Models and it just worked great.